# Fastest way to get nonnegative component

Tags: r, performance, rcpp

What is a faster way to get the nonnegative component of a double vector? That is,

```
pmax(x, 0)
```

My attempt is using Rcpp:

```
//' @title Parallel maximum
//' @description A faster \code{pmax()}.
//'
//' @name pmaxC
//' @param x A numeric vector.
//' @param a A single numeric value.
//' @return The parallel maximum of the input values.
//' @note This function will always be faster than \code{pmax(x, a)} when \code{a} is a single value, but can be slower than \code{pmax.int(x, a)} when \code{x} is short. Use this function when comparing a numeric vector with a single value.
//' @export pmaxC

#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector pmaxC(NumericVector x, double a) {
  int n = x.length();
  NumericVector out(n);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    double xi = x[i];
    if (xi < a) {
      out[i] = a;
    } else {
      out[i] = xi;
    }
  }

  return out;
}
```

This is a modest improvement:

```
set.seed(5)
x <- rnorm(1e6)

microbenchmark(pmax(x, 0), pmaxC(x, 0))
Unit: milliseconds
        expr      min       lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
  pmax(x, 0) 8.500419 8.621341 11.09672 10.132045 10.791020 58.44972   100   a
 pmaxC(x, 0) 5.624480 5.709262  8.83968  7.598093  7.907853 53.91339   100   a
```

Neither are unacceptably slow, but given it is a common scenario, I was wondering whether a package had developed a faster approach.

Comment: `x * (x >= 0)` is an option. If the vector is large and depending on the proportion of negative values, a fast (maybe partial) sorting algorithm could be useful. However, `pmax` is pretty optimized. Why do you need something faster?

Comment: There is a sugar function in Rcpp for pmax. I benchmarked it, and for a single value wasn't any faster. What's the need for the improved speed?

Comment: @Roland No need, but I'm repeating this particular function frequently. I'm just wondering whether there's a function that just checks the sign rather than the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation you are performing is fairly simple, so I'm not sure there is much room for improvement with regard to your algorithm above. However, if you *really* need to squeeze out extra performance, this seems like a good candidate for parallelization. Here is a possible implementation using `RcppParallel`:

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>
#include <Rcpp.h>

struct Pmax : public RcppParallel::Worker {
    struct Apply {
        double mx;
        Apply(double mx_)
            : mx(mx_)
        {}

        double operator()(const double x) const 
        {
            return x > mx ? x : mx;
        }
    };

    const RcppParallel::RVector<double> input;
    RcppParallel::RVector<double> output;

    Apply f; 

    Pmax(const Rcpp::NumericVector input_,
         Rcpp::NumericVector output_,
         double mx_) 
    : input(input_), output(output_), f(mx_)
    {}

    void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end)
    {
        std::transform(
            input.begin() + begin,
            input.begin() + end,
            output.begin() + begin,
            f
        );
    }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector par_pmax(Rcpp::NumericVector x, double y)
{
    Rcpp::NumericVector res = Rcpp::no_init_vector(x.size());
    Pmax p(x, res, y);
    RcppParallel::parallelFor(0, x.size(), p);

    return res;
}
```

---

Testing this with your example data, I get a reasonable improvement:

```
set.seed(5)
x <- rnorm(1e6)

all.equal(pmax(x, 0), par_pmax(x, 0))
#[1] TRUE  

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    pmax(x, 0), 
    pmaxC(x, 0),
    par_pmax(x, 0),
    times = 500L
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#            expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#      pmax(x, 0) 11.843528 12.193126 14.972588 13.030448 16.799250 102.09895   500
#     pmaxC(x, 0)  7.804883  8.036879 10.462070  8.772635 12.407587  69.08290   500
#  par_pmax(x, 0)  2.244691  2.443971  4.552169  2.624008  6.359027  65.99233   500
```